# Use audio capture as a MediaStream source in Web RTC

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

In web RTC, at least using Chrome, it's possible to make a screen capture in order to stream it. [It's accomplished by using the experimental chromeMediaSource constraint.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-constraints)

I would like to do the same but capturing only audio in order to be able to send it to a webpage. I mean, I would like to capture not the micro but the audio 'played' by my machine in order to send it to a website.

Is there such constraint in web RTC? If the answer is 'yes' is there a Firefox equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the [MediaStream Recording API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/default/media-stream-capture/MediaRecorder.html), which has been implemented in Firefox Nightly and has an [Intent to Implement](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/2l_G_apqk30) for Chrome.

I've put a demo at [simpl.info/mediarecorder](http://simpl.info/mediarecorder/).

With Web Audio, try [RecorderJS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs): there's a demo at [webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. I've seen the documentation and I've tried the examples (I've had to install pavucontrol on Ubuntu so they work). I will wait for these capabilities to be implemented in stable releases before developing the web. By the way, congratulations for your tutorial on WebRTC!